# creating libraries

Tags: c++, c, avr

I am practising avr and I have a question , when creating a library, which is better to make a header file that contains the functions declarations and a c file that contain the code(functions definitions), or just making only a header file that contains both the declarations and the definitions of the functions

Comment: Don't put functions in header files. They are called __header files__ for a reason.

Comment: Your question makes a fundamental mistake. It assumes that there's absolutely no difference between the two approaches. This is not true. There are major consequences, code-wise, and you need to understand them fully, in order to make an intelligent decision.

Comment: In neither case are your suggestions related to creating a *library*. It is merely a question of separate compilation and linking vs a single translation unit.  Why tagged embedded? The question is entirely generic.

Answer (score 1):

These two options applicable in different situations:

- If you are writing a template library in C++, header-only option is good, because your library does not have a link-time component. This is how a good portion of the Standard C++ Library (formerly known as STL) is distributed.
- If you are writing a C-style library or a C++ class library, header-only is not an option. You must separate a header from the implementation, compile the implementation into a linkable library, and distribute the header that goes with it. Otherwise, including the same header with definitions in multiple translation units would result in linking-time errors due to duplicate definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Header file only include the prototype that is a declaration of the definition, including both variable and function. It could be included by many other files.

Function definition is where implementation defined and it should be only one.

If you put the function definition in header file and it is included by multiple C files, multiple definition error will arise during compiler phase, specifically during link for multiple object (that include that function definition) into one final object.

There is one case for inline function that must be put in header files, because it is extended during compiler phase, and embedded into the caller function, so compiler must know the implementation during compiler by include that header file.